# XenServer HDD space

Tags: xenserver

I have IBM xServer system with following HDD config.

Total six drives.

1st two drives in Raid1 (270 GB Usable space) & other four in RAID5 (835 GB usable space). Its built-in hardware raid card.
During installation I selected sda (RAID1 drive) as PRIMARY DISK and sdb (RAID5 drive) as VIRTUAL MACHINE DISK. Server up & running from here.

But, after accessing it from XenCenter I seen LOCAL STORAGE with 534GB space. I believe its my 1st two drives showing total HDD space without RAID1. How to configure XenServer to run with RAID1 only?

Then what happened with my other 4 drives (i.e. RAID5 partition).

I am relatively new to XenServer I evaluating it for deployment in our organization.

Thanks,
Sandesh

Comment: You mentioned that the RAID 5 is hardware raid. Is the RAID 1 array also on a hardware raid card?

Comment: Yes. Its a hardware raid..